# Internal PDF link with mPDF

Tags: php, yii, mpdf

I am using mPDF library with yii framework, my PDF is generated properly but now I have to implement internal linking inside PDF. I have tried adding following HTML code but it doesn't seems to work. Has anybody implemented this. Please help

in my controller i have written following line, that is written properly in pdf

```
$_mPDF->WriteHTML('<div name="1b21">test internal</div>');
```

And somewhere in document i have written.

```
$_mPDF->WriteHTML('<a href="#1b21">Host Name</a>');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
$_mPDF->WriteHTML('<div name="1b21">test internal</div>');
```

To,

```
$_mPDF->WriteHTML('<a name="1b21">test internal</a>');
```